# uploaded my laravel 10 on server but admin routes not loading

Tags: laravel

I have uploaded my laravel10 app
frontend works ok but after i login none of admin routes work
i get this error:
[image: error on all admin routes]

I have put all the admin routes inside admin.php and listed in routeServiceProvider.php
[image: admin.php routes]

works fine on local but no idea what is happening on live server
here is the site url: manelroofrestoration.au

i tried dump autoload and clear route and config
it seems can't autoload admin classess

Comment: it stops here in index.php but works on local
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

Comment: Maybe a PSR-4/namespace issue. Try renaming the directory as `Backend` or adding an entry for the directory under in your composer.json under autoload psr-4

Comment: what is the namespace for this `AdminController` and what is the name of the file and the path (in exact case)?

Comment: its not only admin controller all the admin routes having this issue,
I have separated my admin routes inside admin.php and I think somehow thats the issue on the server

Comment: moved all the admin rutes to web.php and tried again and not working

Comment: Share your controller filename and namespace. I already see some inconsistency in your target class `backEnd\AdminController` maybe some capitalization issues.

Comment: Yes thanks to @KnapsackInjury that was PSR-4 problem thanks all of you guys I appreciate your help

Comment: Great you solved it, but this question and answer will never help other users, because nobody will find it - [please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6089612).

Comment: @Don'tPanic I had issue in namespacing for all the admin routes that was the problem, I am sure will be helpful to beginners like me

Comment: Please read the link in my comment. Beginners will never find your question because you posted text as images.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @[KnapsackInjury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13177805/knapsack-injury). It was a PSR-4 problem:

> Maybe a PSR-4/namespace issue. Try renaming the directory as Backend or adding an entry for the directory under in your composer.json under autoload psr-4 –
> [comment link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77520356/uploaded-my-laravel-10-on-server-but-admin-routes-not-loading/77521950#comment136664418_77520356)